# Proposal: country tags for certain classes of questions

Tags: discussion, tags

Some time back, we got a question about which operators offer the Animax channel in India - [On which DTH operator can I get Animax channel in India?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/20995/). This is a topic that would benefit from the experience of anime-consumers who have specific knowledge about India. As such, I have created a tag [india](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india) and applied it to that question, with the following excerpt:

> For India-specific questions about anime, e.g. which channels to watch, how to find merchandise, etc.

Other questions that could benefit from a country-specific tag include:

- [When and where can we order/buy region-free DVD/Blu-Ray of Digimon Adventure tri.?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/27917/) (if OP had specified their location)
- [Where do I go to purchase Chinese manhua?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/26798/) - [united-states](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states)
- Probably many other [merchandise](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merchandise) questions, and a few [resources](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) questions.

We should probably forego a [japan](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japan) tag, since that's generally implied. Likewise, no [south-korea](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/south-korea) for general-purpose questions about manhua, but a [south-korea](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/south-korea) tag would be useful for questions about acquiring Japanese anime in South Korea.

Does this seem like a good idea?

(Possible future extensions of this concept: [anglosphere](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anglosphere) for questions like [Is Guilty Crown on DVD in the USA, UK, or Australia?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3727/); tags for specific BD/DVD regions [because of region locking]; etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where I stand on this, but I don't see why we can't trial it as it shouldn't affect too many questions.

My only reservation is that these could become hundreds of tags that aren't that useful or questions will be applying a lot of tags needlessly. This also runs somewhat contrary to the 'too localized' rule that is often on SE networks. (We don't necessarily have to take that rule on ourselves though)

I think we should keep an eye out for unnecessary tagging of these on unintended questions.

Comment: A question/tag that (potentially) applies to the one billion people who live in India (or even the one million people who apparently live in Swaziland) should not be construed as "too localized". This was a dumb and frequently misapplied close reason, and I'm glad it's gone.

Comment: @senshin while India is not small, many other countries are. A Luxembourg tag for example

Comment: My point is that the notion of "too localized" was (or at least should have been) intended to mean "this question only helps the author and literally nobody else". Questions that are potentially relevant to an entire country's worth of people are not that.