# Should the Europe tag have been used for these questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed recently that a tag for [europe](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe) exists, which seems to serve the purpose outlined [here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2702/2604). However, currently there are only two questions in it, which look like they could be better served with country-specific tags:

- [Non-independent stores in the UK that sell manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/30557/2604): [united-kingdom](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom) seems more appropriate.
- [Where can I read Bleach legally?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/26956/2604): [norway](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norway) seems more appropriate. In particular, licensing restrictions may not uniformly apply across Europe. (e.g. This is what I extrapolated from [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/30593/2604).)

I can surely imagine instances where the tag could be useful (e.g. when asking about conventions), but I'm less sure of the fit in these specific cases.

Comment: this one also which I just added: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/18464/how-much-english-is-spoken-at-japan-expo-paris/19795#19795 (France)

Comment: How granular should we get - UK can be split into several areas too. We could have >200 country-based tags

Comment: I also found these, which have country-based tags: [Greece](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/30928/2604), [Spain](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/28950/2604).

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko: I'm not sure about tag "precision". Maybe it should be on a case-by-case basis? Either way, country-level tags at least seem like a good place to stop, somehow, but I'm not entirely sure.